# Why does it give me unexpected unindent=

Tags: python

Why does the function `crear_bd` gives me unexpected indent? I think that is in a good position or its something else that could be affecting this? I defined the crear_bd function, I just didn't include it here. I'm a beginner.

```python
def agregar_categoria():
    categoria = input("¿Como quieres nombrar a la nueva categoria?\n> ")

    conexion = sqlite3.connect("restaurante.db")
    cursor = conexion.cursor()

    try:
        cursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO categoria (null, '{}')'''.format(categoria))

        conexion.commit()
        conexion.close()
    
crear_bd()

while True:
    print("\nBienvenido al gestor del restaurante!")
    opcion = input("\nIntroduce una opción:\n[1] Agregar una categoría\n ")
```

Comment: your `try` is missing an `except`

Comment: I happens most of the time when you use both tabs and space for indentation. Choose either of them and make sure each block should have indentation of 4 spaces or 1 tab

Comment: Don't choose "either". Always use 4 spaces for Python.

Comment: The `try` is not aligned with the lines above. For your future questions, please always include the complete error traceback which contains the line causing the error, that will avoid (wrong) guesses.

Comment: Btw he's a new contributor so indentation can be a result of improper use of SO code snippet ;) just saying :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you cannot use a `try` without an `except` or `finally`.
So just add an `except:` block beneath your `try` block and it should work fine.
You can simply do an

```
except:
   pass
```

to ignore all exceptions, but I would not recommend this. It is better to think of an useful exception handling.

This is no problem of mixing spaces and tabs, although this is often the source of `unexpected unindent`. But in this case, python expects the `except` block and this block needs to be indented. So the missing `except` is hidden behind the `unindent` error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the try block was not properly indented

```
  categoria = input("¿Como quieres nombrar a la nueva categoria?\n> ")

  conexion = sqlite3.connect("restaurante.db")
  cursor = conexion.cursor()
  try:
      cursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO categoria (null, '{}')'''.format(categoria))
      conexion.commit()
      conexion.close()
  except:
      pass      
      
    
crear_bd()

while True:
       print("\nBienvenido al gestor del restaurante!")
       opcion = input("\nIntroduce una opción:\n[1] Agregar una categoría\n ")
```

Answer (score -2):

For Sublime Text users:

Set your editor to use tabs for indentation: View --> Indentation --> Convert Indentation to Tabs

Also, uncheck the `Indent Using Spaces` option as well in the same sub-menu above.

This error happens when you use space and tabs for indentation.